# useReducer duplicates the added elements

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

Why are two elements added instead of one?

[My codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useredux-duplicates-the-added-elements-lkste9)

I apologize for such a short description, but I do not know what else to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved your issue... however please refer to the [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

The issue is here

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "push":
      state.arr.push(action.payload);
      return { arr: state.arr };
    default:
  }
}
```

It should be like this, this is the typical reducer flow utilizing the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
   function reducer(state, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "push":
          return {
            ...state,
            // spread the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, && action.paylod appends the number/item to the array
            arr: [...state.arr, action.payload] // pass the action payload 
          }
        default:
      }
    }
```

Working demo

https://codesandbox.io/embed/useredux-duplicates-the-added-elements-forked-grznpc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I understand I need to make the array meet the condition: state.arr !== returned state.arr. For example, this code is also working.

      const arr = Array.from(state.arr);
      arr.push(action.payload);

      return { arr };